# fancybox. Запуск видео с YouTube

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube, fancybox

Вот HTML

```
<a href="#" data-src="https://youtu.be/Z-F6PoY7ofE" class="br_slide_1" data-fancybox>
  <img src="img/sl_1_img.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

При клике открывается фансибокс попап но не запускается видео автоматически. Нужно чтобы видео с YouTube запускалось автоматически. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

за автозапуск видео отвечает сам ютюб код

поэтому стоит попробовать изменить data-src, вот так:

```
data-src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z-F6PoY7ofE?autoplay=1"
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).